# Which of the following values are possible for $P (A\cup B \cup C) $?

Tags: probability

Let A, B and C be events in a common probability space with $P (A)=0.2$, $P (B)=0.2$, $P (C)=0.3$, $P (A\cap B)=0.1$, $P (A\cap C)=P (B\cap C)=0.1$.
Which of the following are possible values for $P(A\cup B \cup C)$?
1. 0.5
2. 0.3
3. 0.4
4. 0.9.
I know that $P(A\cup B \cup C)= 0.4+ P (A\cap B \cap C)$.
So now the possible values of $P(A\cup B \cup C)$ depends on the possible values of  $P(A\cap B \cap C)$, which cannot be negative and cannot be greater than 0.1. So I think the answer has to be options (1) and (3). Am I correct? Is there anyway of finding the actual values?

Comment: You are correct, and there is no way to narrow it down further with the information given.

Comment: @Ceph can the value of the probability of the intersection A, B and C be 0.1 also?

Comment: Yes, it can. Example: Consider a 10-sided fair die, rolled once to get random value $X$. Let $A$ be the event $X\in\{1,2\}$, $B$ be $X\in \{2,3\}$, and $C$ be $X\in \{2,4,5\}$. Then $P(A)=P(B)=.2,$ $P(C)=.3$, and $$P(A\cap B) = P(A\cap C) = P(B\cap C) = P(A\cap B\cap C) = P(X=2)=.1$$ and $P(A\cup B\cup C)=P(X\in\{1,2,3,4,5\})=.5$.

Comment: @Ceph Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said:

$\Bbb P (A \cup B \cup C) = \Bbb P (A) + \Bbb P (B) + \Bbb P (C) - \Bbb P (A\cap B) - \Bbb P (B\cap C) -\Bbb P (A\cap C) + \Bbb P (A \cap B \cap C)\\ = 0.4 + \Bbb P (A \cap B \cap C)$

$ 0 \leq \Bbb P (A\cap B \cap C ) \leq \Bbb P (A\cap B ) = 0.1 \Rightarrow 0.4 \leq \Bbb P (A\cup B \cup C)\leq0.5$

Possibilities left: 1. and 3.

Comment: can it be 0.5 also?

Comment: Yes. Cephs comment says it all.